# Custom UITableViewCell has no initialiser error on only one of the two created classes. Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview

I'm adding a new `TableVIew`to the project and I'm also creating a custom class fro the `cell`. I'm doing as usual : New file/ Cocoa Touch Class / UITableViewCell / name. As soon as I start adding properties I get the error dough properties are declared as`!`. It doesn't happen on my other custom cell class. Can you see what am I doing wrong with this new class?

No error on this class :

```
import UIKit

class CalendarTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var dayLabel: UILabel!
    var cellId: String!
    var cellWeekday: Int!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }
    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        // Set your default background color, title color etc

    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

and the new class that makes xCode complain:

```
import UIKit

class ProductTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var productImageView: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var productIDLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var productIDInfoLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var categoryLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var categoryInfoLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var nameInfoLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var priceLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var priceInfoLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var quantityLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var quantityInfoLabel: UILabel!


    var productImage: UIImage!
    var category: String!
    var productId: String!
    var name: String!
    var price: String
    var vendor: String!



    var cellId: Int64


    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

It's something I overlooked for sure but I can't spot it.
What should I check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `var cellId: Int64` is not initialized. In first cell you explicitly specified that you will initialize it before use with exclamation mark, but not in the second cell.

Comment: yeap.. I couldn't see it man.. thank you so much.. I guess Sunday I'd be better stay off the code..